# Imageview is not aligned properly

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

This is what I have to do:

[image]

And this is what I have done:

[image]

As you can see that there is a little gap between the kangaroo and the image.I have absolutely no clue why this is happening.Help.

Relevant code:

```
<RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout_image"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.1" >
        <ImageView //This is the kangaroo pic
             android:id="@+id/layout_image_fox"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/fox_holding_pic"


            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_image_fox"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp">
         <!--    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"  -->

            <!-- android:layout_below="@+id/txt_scene_adress" -->

            <ImageView   //this is the footballer pic
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_image"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/> 

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Update:**

First of all Thanks to all of you for helping me.After some research and from some answers here I have updated my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout_image"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.1" >
        <ImageView 
             android:id="@+id/layout_image_fox"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/fox_holding_pic"


            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp" 
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_image_fox" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_image"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My result is now:

[image]

Still the footballer image is not clipped with that of the kangaroo.Should I use frame layout or I should change something from the existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have to take a frame layout to make it work.So that claw of the fox clipped with the image:

The code:

```
  <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout_image"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"> 

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_image"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/layout_image_fox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/fox_holding_pic" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="-18dp"

                />

 </FrameLayout>
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your image(kangaroo) have this transparent margin to the left which causes that margin, also you added margin left to the football player image which will have a gap for 5dp.

**solution:**

since you already set the `android:cropToPadding` to true then you can use a negative value for `android:layout_marginLeft` to position that image and clip it to the kangaroo image. You could have a different value than mine just make sure that you position to your liking.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp" <--- negative value 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
```

Comment: yes you are right.There is a transparent border of 10-12 pixels after the fox image.I removed that and set -20dp marginleft.But the problem is still there.

Comment: @kgandroid use -20dp not 20

Comment: yes i had set -20 dp...not 20dp...and as a result the left black margin of the footballer pic is gone.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin don't suggest -ve margins to UI :|

Answer (score 0):

set gravity

```
android:gravity="center"
```

to ur imageview and remove margins

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_image"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ImageView //kangaroo
        android:id="@+id/layout_image_fox"
        android:layout_width="xyz"
        android:layout_height="abc"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="XYZdp"
    />
    <ImageView  ///footballer
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_image_fox"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i cannot remove the liner layout.I have done some work with it in my java pages.